# What is this yellow pillar of light from the sky?

Tags: planetside-2

During a battle for a minor base, this yellow pillar of light appeared in the base. What exactly does it mean?

[image: Light Pillar]

Some additional information:

- As far as I could tell, the pillar went all the way up to the skybox
- It stayed there for a quite long time. Not sure for how long, but certainly several minutes.
- There was no minimap icon at that position
- I was not in a platoon/squad at this time

Comment: A full picture of your HUD, including the minimap could help

Answer (score 1):

Its a marker a squad leader or platoon leader can place. It shows up the map, minimap and in-game.
It acts as a waypoint that every player in the squad/platoon can see.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this seems to be incorrect. As I wrote in the question, I was not in a platoon/squad at this time and there was no minimap icon at that position.

Comment: sorry about that.
Were you in a squad previously?
If so it could just be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This waypoint is marked by the game's **mission system**. You can toggle this on/off in options.
[image: screenshot]
It's purpose is to help new players accomplish objectives such as outpost capture.

OP's image shows the bridge at Naum Ravine Overpass where the capture point is underneath the structure.

Answer (score -1):

Since a platoon/squad waypoint can be ruled out, I think it's probably from the games "mission" system. The game will assign arbitrary missions like "capture this base" or "defend this base" from time to time and if I recall correctly, the respective facilities are marked with this yellow pillar. The objectives also change quite frequently depending on player position (usually nearby bases are picked) and situation (e.g. enemy attack on a base).

As I wrote in a comment, a full picture of your HUD would help to confirm this.